# 3GP video thumbnails not displayed

Tags: nautilus, video, thumbnails, nemo

3GP/3GPP (.3gp) videos have no thumbnails in Nautilus or Nemo.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Add `video/3gpp;` to the *MimeType* section in `/usr/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer`.

Then clear the thumbnail cache:

```
cd ~/.thumbnails
rm -r fail
rm -r normal
rm -r large
```